# Range Min, Max, step, doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, material-design, rangeslider

I try to create a slider range with Material Design style. 
I integrate this codepen : [Read](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxYZMP)

My HTML :

```
<div class="chauffage_settings_area_slider_temp">
    <div class="rkmd-slider slider-discrete slider-lightBlue slider-light" style="width: 575px;" id="slider_temp">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="30" step="30" value="19" id="st">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to personalize this slider to range from 1 to 30.
Since few hours, I tried to find a solution, but doesn't find it.

Do you have some tips to resolve my problem?

Thanks for your time and helps,

Comment: its working bro

Comment: It doesn't work at all in Chrome. Setting the step to a smaller value some what works but doesn't allow the slider to move all the way to the right.

Comment: My slider range is from 1 to 100 with properties min="1", max="30"... It doesn't work on Safari too... @Turnip, with this edit : min="0,00" max="0,30" step="0,01" value="0,12". It not does work too....

Comment: `step` increments/decrements the value by N every time the user interacts with the slider (eg. 30, 60, 90, etc). Is this what you're after?

Comment: I think, something doesn't work with the jQuery script, he doesn't take importance at these parameters.